# Is there any better approach to get notification about changes in SQL SERVER database?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

This may be a silly question ,but please help me sort this.

I have a `SQL` database with tables and whenever there is row added/deleted/updated ..(any operation) in the table a notification should be available through a desktop `c#` app running in system tray.

> There is already notification mail sending mechanism in `SQL SERVER`
>   but i dont want to get notified by mail.

Mail notification screen below :

[image]

Is there any better approach to get notification through app even if the database is modified via management studio?

> I used to check the count of rows and will get notified if count is
>   increased / decreased i would be notified about inserting / deleting
>   of rows .

But that doesnt apply for update !

**Edit 1 :**

How to overcome if possibilities are available for arising limitation situations like [this Stack Overflow post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588572/what-are-the-limitations-of-sqldependency/7588660#7588660) for **SqlDependency** ?

Comment: You get number of rows updated though?

Comment: Have you heard about Notification Services?

Comment: That sounds horrible... but: in your scenario, what is the connected system that you want to be notified?

Comment: @MarcGravell thank you for your time..is there any work around for that situation ? How can we achieve that

Comment: @utility that depends: *what is the connected system that you want to be notified*? What is the context here? What is the problem you are trying to solve? Personally, I would (and indeed: do) use pub/sub that is completely  separate to SQL-Server and the database - i.e. if I'm doing something other code will want to know about: change the data *and* publish a message to a pub/sub channel.

Comment: a c# application is the connecting system here..Hearing SqlDependency first time..do that consume system resource for constantly checking the database?..@MarcGravell please do share some light about that pub/sub

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for [SqlDependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) .

And more specifically, the [OnChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.onchange%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event.

<sub>(There's also the [SqlCommand.Notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.notification%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I made a small sample for you

create for each table a trigger for Inserting, Updating and deleting. Perhaps use a History table for each table , this way all your changes are recorded as well

Create a table as follows

```
Create Table Notifications
(
 Id bigint Identity(1,1) Not null,
 TableName nvarchar(250),
 ChangedOn DateTime,
 Notified bit
)
```

each time your trigger happens write to the notifications table the following values:

```
Insert Into Notifications
(TableName, ChangedOn, Notified)
Values
('YourTableName', GetDate(), 0)
```

Create an application with an easy timer that will periodically check the table values as follows:

ie: C#

```
private List<Notification> _notificationsToShow;

Private void DoNotify()
{
    var notifs = Notifications.Where(t=> !t.Notified).ToList();
    if(notifs.Count > 0)
    {
        _notificationsToShow.AddRange(notifs);            
        foreach(var Notification in notifs)
        {
            //Save to database as user is notified
            Notification.Notified = true;
            Notification.Save(); 
        }            
    }
    DoSomethingAlertish();
}

private void DoSomethingAlertish()
{  
    if(_notificationToShow.Count == 0 || _notificationToShow == null)
        return;

    var s = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(var v in _notificationToShow)
    {
        s.AppendLine(v.TableName);
    }
    alert(s.ToString());
}

//Create an event that will empty the list (user must do trigger this action)
private void UserNotifiedAction() 
{
    _notificationToShow = new List<Notification>();
    DoSomethingAlertish();
}
```

The **downsize** of this method is the following:

for each table triggers must be created. This means 3 triggers per table

so when you have a small application with for example 15 tables this already means the creation of 45 triggers, now do think of a situation with 1000 tables, you get the point.

Also, be aware that the Notifications table will grow like a maniac. So perhaps you need to clean it now and then.

the **good** part is then that after creating all your triggers and storing the values in the table, you can use whatever technology available to create a notification. You want it in the tray bar now, perhaps in the future you still want a mail, everything is already running and collecting all your values, the only part where you then have to think about is what technology to call it with.

I hope i provided you with a solution that can help you in the future. Again, the solution you ask can be simpler but it depends how future-aimed you are.