# how to monitor updating data real-time by sored procedure string query in MVC?

Tags: c#, sql, signalr, sqldependency

What methods can I use to monitor updating data real-time ?
Returned data from following stored procedure that write as string query :

```
BEGIN TRAN

USE [MyDataBase]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[MySp]
(    
    @UserId INT
)
as
BEGIN

CREATE TABLE #tmp (T1 INT,T2 NVARCHAR(500))
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @sql='select  [T1], [dbo].[MyFunction]('+ cast(@UserId as nvarchar(20))+',[T1],0) as [T2]
          from [dbo].[MyTable]               
          where ( [X] in(50,60) or [Y] in(520,530) ) and  [dbo].[MyFunction]('+ cast(@UserId as nvarchar(20)) +',[T1],0) <>0'

    sp_executesql @sql        
END
```

**EDIT 1 :**

The procedure non string query is :

```
BEGIN TRAN

USE [MyDataBase]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[MySp]
(    
    @UserId INT
)
as
BEGIN

select  [T1], [dbo].[MyFunction]('+ cast(@UserId as nvarchar(20))+',[T1],0) as [T2]
          from [dbo].[MyTable]               
          where ( [X] in(50,60) or [Y] in(520,530) ) and  [dbo].[MyFunction]('+ cast(@UserId as nvarchar(20)) +',[T1],0) <> 0       
END
```

But also this method not correct working.What to do?

Answer (score 0):

SQLDependency doesn't work with temporal tables.

Please see [What are the limitations of SqlDependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588572/what-are-the-limitations-of-sqldependency)

Comment: I do not have a temporary table, however, does not work.

Comment: And what is this: "CREATE TABLE #tmp (T1 INT,T2 NVARCHAR(500))"

Comment: Please see the Edit1.

Comment: And what about MyFunction, Is it deterministic?. Does it access data in the database?

Comment: Yes,Is it deterministic.Why not working?what to do for return  result؟What do I use for this item?how change procedure to return true result?