# SQL Server Query Notifications using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, query-notifications

I am trying to implement query notifications for a current project. I'm implementing query notifications using `SqlDependency`. I'm able to get the code to work when I do inline SQL for the query directly in the Ado.net command, however, when I put the same exact query in a stored procedure the query notification doesn't seem to work. It returns in the `SqlNotificationEventArgs` the value of Query(8) in the `e.Info` parameter of the event args. It also continues to fire approx. every 30+ seconds.

```
Public Sub GetCust(ByVal CustomerId As String)

    Dim oConn As SqlConnection

    Dim connectionString As string

    connectionString = GetConnectionString()

    SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString)

    SqlDependency.Start(connectionString)

    oConn = New SqlConnection(connectionString)

'This is the code for the stored procedure path
    'Dim oCommand As New SqlCommand("SelectCustomerInfo", oConn)
    'oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    'oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerId", CustomerId)

'This is the code for using inline SQL
    Dim strSQL As String

    strSQL = "select [CustomerId],[name], [age],[gender],[favorite_food] from dbo.custpreferences where customerid = '" & CustomerId & "'"

    Dim oCommand As New SqlCommand(strSQL, oConn)
    oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    oCommand.Notification = Nothing

    Dim dep As SqlDependency = New SqlDependency(oCommand)

    AddHandler dep.OnChange, AddressOf cust_onchange

    oConn.Open()

    Dim dataAdapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(oCommand)

    dataAdapter.Fill(dsCustomers)

    If (Not dataAdapter Is Nothing) Then dataAdapter.Dispose()

    If Not oConn Is Nothing Then oConn.Dispose()

End Sub

Private Sub cust_onchange(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlNotificationEventArgs)

    GetCustInfo(mCustomer.strCustomerID)

    Dim dep As SqlDependency = DirectCast(sender, SqlDependency)

    RemoveHandler dep.OnChange, AddressOf cust_onchange

End Sub
```

Here's the stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON 
GO
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON 
GO
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON 
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO 
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
GO 
SET ARITHABORT ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectCustInfo]
    @CustomerID VARCHAR(6)
AS 
    SELECT
        [CustomerId], [name], [age], [gender], [favorite_food] 
    FROM     
        dbo.CustInfo (NOLOCK)
     WHERE    
        (CustomerId = @CustomerID)
```

Any ideas why this works with inline SQL vs using a stored procedure?

Comment: Have you tried removing `nolock`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/29948293/123422

Comment: Hi @PaulAbbott.  Thanks for the recommendation.  For some reason, I didn't think to remove that.  Once I did, It worked.  So Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work once I removed the NOLOCK hint which is the same as READ UNCOMMITED.

Answer (score 0):

When using Store procedure with `SqlDependency`

Do not use

1. NOLOCK
2. SET NOCOUNT ON