# Realtime filtered list using SignalR and SqlDependecies c#

Tags: c#, optimization, signalr, real-time, sqldependency

I've the following scenario: my homepage is a "timeline" where I have a map, some filters on the top and a list of posts below.
The list is filtered by map bounds (spatial query) and 2 other filters (category and free text search).

I wanna implement it using `SignalR` and `SQL Dependencies` (SQL Server 2016) to make it "real time" (like: notify the user when new posts for its set filters are available) but I've some implementation doubts:

To do that I need to register a SQL Dependency for each unique combination of filters (search, category, map_bounds) but of course this translates to a potential infinite number of SQL Dependecies and I suppose this will be a huge overload for the servers infrastructure

How can I do that in an optimized way? I need some advice :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done, but because of the limitations of the query that is used for the dependency, it might prove to be quite a challenge. For what you are trying to do I would not recommend SQL dependency injections. You might want to look at using something like redis to cache your data and query the in cache data for what you are trying to do. Here is SO question that has all of the limitations for SQL dependency injection query.

[What are the limitations of SqlDependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588572/what-are-the-limitations-of-sqldependency)

Comment: No, you cannot search redis by value. A better scenario would be to have 2 caches, one for your spatial, and one for your title, with the keys reversed, this will give you what you need, and you can do that behind the scenes as your web application loads, it doesn't necessarily need to be when the application starts, it can be used as you need it with a subset of data, possibly on mouse over if the data is small enough, etc. –

Comment: Ok, Thank you! I'll try to figure out how to implement it

Comment: @Enricosoft don't forget to mark it as the answer :)