# SqlTableDependency: text column type is not an supported by SqlTableDependency

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, sqldependency

i'm implementing first exemple of sqlDependency and i have this Excepetion  "text column type is not an supported by SqlTableDependency" when  declaring "SqlTableDependency"
this is my code:

```
string connectS= "Data Source =.; Initial Catalog = mydb; MultipleActiveResultSets = True; Persist Security Info = True; User ID = sa; Password = mypass";
using (var tableDep = new SqlTableDependency<Primitive>(connectS, "mytable"))
        {
            tableDep.OnChanged += OnChange;
            tableDep.OnError += OnError;
            tableDep.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("WAIT");
            Console.WriteLine("Press");
            Console.ReadKey();
            tableDep.Stop();

        }...
```

The Excpetion is in second line:
(var tableDep = new SqlTableDependency(connectS, "mytable"))

Is there someone who had the same problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the limitations of SqlDependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588572/what-are-the-limitations-of-sqldependency)

Comment: `TEXT` has been deprecated for a very long time. It's not surprising query notifications don't support it. Migrate your column to the supported type `VARCHAR(MAX)`, or make the dependency use a query that does not include any `TEXT` columns.

Comment: Yes i  changed colums to nvarchar  and it works thanks

Comment: Now in my work project  i cant change columns type. is there another possibility to fix it?

Comment: No, there is not - as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588572/what-are-the-limitations-of-sqldependency .

Comment: As long as you don't care about notifications when the `TEXT` column is modified, you can use an `SqlDependency` that uses an explicit query (e.g. `SELECT ID FROM MyTable`). If you do need to know when the `TEXT` column is modified, you can't use query notifications. Use another mechanism, like a trigger that sends a message on a service broker conversation.

Comment: i will try with triggers