# After enable SQL broker service, the LOG FILE SIZE INCREASE

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

i make the application in the SignalR usign SQL DEPENDENCY, the enable the BrOKER SERIVCE. my application working fine, but i see the huge bug that my LOG FILE of the databse is increase continously. So can you suggest me what can i do for this.

I know to shrink the database whenever the log file , but if i schedule the SHRINKING of LOG FILE i study it may be harm for database at production time.

so please suggest me how can i make it easier  or is their is another method to make the chat application in the ASP.net using C#.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the minimum columns in Sql dependency query or SP. You need to be specific for column and select only that are required this will generate less logs. Logs are generated whenever there is a change in result.[see this for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588572/what-are-the-limitations-of-sqldependency?answertab=active#tab-top)

Hope this helps you.