# Why does my SqlDependancy OnChange() event not fire?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to implement a SqlDependancy to fire events when a change is made to one of the tables in MySQL server database, however the event does not seem to fire when I make alterations to the table through SSMS, why could this be?

My implmentation below is inline with Microsofts [tuturiol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency):

```
public int GetVehicleCount(bool monitorCount)
{
      int count;          
      string query = "SELECT AREA_ID, VEHICLE_COUNT, ADDED_ON FROM CAPACITY_LOG";

      using (var sql = DBClass.Instance.OpenSqlConn())
      using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sql))
      {                  
           SqlDependency sqlDependancy = new SqlDependency(cmd);

           sqlDependancy.OnChange += new ChangeEventHandler(VehicleCount_Changed);

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {                            
                //Do something    
            }       

            return 0;
     }
}

private void VehicleCount_Changed(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
     //throw new NotImplementedException();            
}
```

I have made sure of the following:

- The connection to the database can be opened.
- The database has the Service-Broker enabled.
- The SqlDependancy has been started.
- No exceptions are being thrown during runtime

Note that the event fires once shortly after it has been subscribed to and never again, below are the values of the event args:
[image]

Comment: Because of the beauty of GC

Comment: @DanielTshuva do you mean that because the sql dependancy is declared within the using block it is being removed by the garbage collecter after that block is executed?

Comment: yes I think so.

Comment: @Abs, you need to resubscribe after the notification is fired to get notified again. What are the values of the initial SqlNotificationEventArgs? Perhaps it erred.

Comment: @DanGuzman Please see the image in the update, not entirely sure what the values of those properties are spoused to indicate yet

Comment: The info `Invalid` means the SQL statement isn't valid for notifications. You must use 2-part names, like `dbo.CAPACITY_LOG`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588572/what-are-the-limitations-of-sqldependency

Comment: @DanGuzman Thanks that did the trick, it does seem like I have to resubscribe, not sure how to do that without making the sql dependancy object a property of the class. If you create an answer i'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Queries with a `SqlDependency` [have a number of requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588572/what-are-the-limitations-of-sqldependency). When a query is executed that doesn't meet these requirements, the `ChangeEventHandler` fires immediately with `Invalid` in `SqlNotificationEventArs.Info`.

In this case, the query is invalid because the table name was not schema-qualified. Specify a 2-part name so that the query is valid for notifications. This example assumes the dbo schema:

```
string query = "SELECT AREA_ID, VEHICLE_COUNT, ADDED_ON FROM dbo.CAPACITY_LOG";
```

This change should result in a valid `SqlDependency`. Note that when the `ChangeEventHander` is invoked, the normal pattern is to execute the query again with SqlDependency, which will get the latest data and re-subscribe to change notifications.

Answer (score 0):

The connection is disposed of, so it stops receiving input from the database. I have a code sample available at https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/broadcasting-database-changes-through-signalr that does work.